# How to make clicked button in Tkinter Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using Python 3.5.

I want to make a button invisible and I found it:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def hide_btn():
    def hide_me(event):
        event.widget.pack_forget()

    root = Tk()

    hiddenbtn = Button(root, text = 'Hello World')
    hiddenbtn.place(x = 0, y = 0)

    hiddenbtn.bind('<Button-1>', hide_me)
    hiddenbtn.pack()

    root.mainloop()

hide_btn()
```

It works well, but I want to make the button clicked.

Is there any way to make it clicked?

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to make the button clicked.*?

Comment: Well, when you run the program, the button is shown. And when you click the button, the button become invisible. I want to make the button invisible from the first time. So I want to make the button clicked.

Comment: Yes. Exactly right.

Comment: Well, when I change my code, AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'lbl' comes out.

Comment: If you don't want the widget shown, just don't `place`/`pack` it until you do want it to be shown? (Also don't use both `place` and `pack` for widgets in the same master, let alone for one widget. Pick one.)

Comment: @fhdrsdg Oh, it's nice. Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you do not need to bind the button, you can simple rely on [`place_forget()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place_forget-method) to do the job. This is what I mean:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def hide_btn():       

    root = Tk()

    hiddenbtn = Button(root, text = 'Hello World')
    hiddenbtn.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    hiddenbtn.place_forget()      

    root.mainloop()

hide_btn()
```